# in C#, What does the "@" symbol do?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the @ in front of a string for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-for-net)

Sometimes i saw the sample code, will have a "@" symbol along with the string.
for example:

```
    EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5";
    entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;
    entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/App_Data.data.csdl|res://*/App_Data.data.ssdl|res://*/App_Data.data.msl";
```

On the 4th line, what is that usage of the "@"?
I try to remove this, it still works.

Comment: An excellent question, but it is worth checking out the existing explanations first.

Comment: btw, in this case it doesn't change anything, as nothing there needs escaping

Comment: Wow. That was closed within 30 seconds. Good job Marc :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string literal such as @"c:\Foo" is called a verbatim string literal. It basically means, "don't apply any interpretations to characters until the next quote character is reached". So, a verbatim string literal can contain backslashes (without them being doubled-up) and even line separators. To get a double-quote (") within a verbatim literal, you need to just double it, e.g. @"My name is ""Jon""" represents the string My name is "Jon". Verbatim string literals which contain line separators will also contain the white-space at the start of the line, so I tend not to use them in cases where the white-space matters. They're very handy for including XML or SQL in your source code though, and another typical use (which doesn't need line separators) is for specifying a file system path.

[Taken from](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx)

Comment: (while external links are useful, they tend to disappear unpredictably; having some content in the actual post is preferred)

Answer (score 1):

It tells the compiler not to treat `\` as escape sequences and take the strings literally.