# C# '@' before a String

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the @ in front of a string for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-for-net)

I found this in a C# study book

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(key.Key.ToString() + @":\");
```

The book however did not explain what the '@' symbol was for.  I tried searching [MSDN C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=VS.100).aspx) but its not listed there.  I can guess that it allows the developer to not have to escape a '\' or does it allow to not have any escape sequences?

What is this for and why would I use `@":\"` instead of `":\\"`?

Thanks for the help

Edit: See the comment below for a similar question

Comment: can I point out how counter productive it is to close as duplicates and list the names of the people who felt that way but not a link to the duplicated post?  You have done nothing to prevent Google from directing people to this page which you do not allow answers too, and provide no link...

Comment: @Dan the link to possible duplicates is at the top under "Possible Duplicate" and on the right under "Linked"

Answer (score 237, accepted):

It means to interpret the string literally (that is, you cannot escape any characters within the string if you use the @ prefix). It enhances readability in cases where it can be used.

For example, if you were working with a UNC path, this:

```
@"\\servername\share\folder"
```

is nicer than this:

```
"\\\\servername\\share\\folder"
```

Comment: Well you can escape " by doubling them up i.e. `string S = @""""; Console.Write("[{0}]", S);` writes `[""]`

Comment: @Mark So any escape sequence in the string would be ignored and treated at literal text?

Comment: @Daniel: correct; any sequence that would otherwise be backslash-escaped will be treated literally. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=VS.100).aspx explains further and gives examples.

Comment: +1, I never realized you can  double " to escape it. I always hated not being able to escape " when using @. I feel dumb now. Thanks...

Answer (score 84):

It also means you can use reserved words as variable names

say you want a class named class,  since class is a reserved word, you can instead call your class class:

```
IList<Student> @class = new List<Student>();
```

Comment: Thats pretty cool - I didn't know you could do that. Thanks

Comment: True but off topic.

Answer (score 26):

Prefixing the string with an @ indicates that it should be treated as a literal, i.e. no escaping.

For example if your string contains a path you would typically do this:

```
string path = "c:\\mypath\\to\\myfile.txt";
```

The @ allows you to do this:

```
string path = @"c:\mypath\to\myfile.txt";
```

Notice the lack of double slashes (escaping)

Answer (score 10):

As a side note, you also should keep in mind that "escaping" means "using the back-slash as an indicator for special characters". You can put an end of line in a string doing that, for instance:

```
String foo = "Hello\

There";
```

Comment: +1 I always though the newline was exclusively to @"... style

Answer (score 2):

> What is this for and why would I use @":\" instead of ":\"?

Because when you have a long string with many `\` you don't need to escape them all and the `\n`, `\r` and `\f` won't work too.

Comment: pardon me, there's a misspell in "string" word.