# lose \ when using ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to insert a single value into an SQL Database. It works fine as long as I don't insert a "\". If I do, then I lose a "\" in the database.

For example, in the debugger I see this Command Text:

```
Insert into tblProjekte (Projektbezeichnung) values ('\\bla\\bla\\bla')
```

But in the SQL Server Profiler I always find this Insert Statement:

```
Insert into tblProjekte (Projektbezeichnung) values ('\bla\bla\bla')
```

My source code:

```
public void InsertProjekt(string Projektbezeichnung)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=myProjekt; UID=user; PWD=pwd";
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = String.Format("Insert into tblProjekte (Projektbezeichnung) values ('{0}')",@Projektbezeichnung);
    int rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();        
}
```

After I changed my Source Code to:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblProjekte (Projektbezeichnung) VALUES (@Projektbezeichnung)");
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Projektbezeichnung", Projekt.Projektbezeichnung);
```

I get this information during debugging:
[image]

The Value is "\\Tesafilm"
the SQLValue is "\Tesafilm"

Comment: You are inserting an SQL escape character.

Comment: You really should be using parameters and not inline formatting.  This is wide open for SQL injection.  Use @param and then add the parameter with value to your command and you should be good.

Comment: The fact that you put `@` before your variable name doesn't mean you're using a parameterized query. You should use a real parameter.

Comment: what is the issue? Please post question clearly

Comment: Please don't prefix tables with `tbl`.

Comment: @hvd I use the @ not as a parmeter I use it for C# not to lose my "\"

Comment: @Ehsan Ullah In SQLServer I received a different string than I expected, I always miss a "\" in my my SQLServer data.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for this really helpfull comment. I think this will not really helps me fixing my issue and it also does not help me to understand what I made wrong.

Comment: Other people are responding to your original problem. It is a comment and not an answer for a reason. [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is something of the eighties and should be avoided.

Comment: @ReneRies That's not what `@` means before a variable name. Before a variable name, `@` means "whatever follows is not a keyword", and can be used to create variables with names such as "object". `@Projektbezeichnung` and `Projektbezeichnung` mean *exactly* the same thing in C#, since `Projektbezeichnung` already isn't a keyword.

Comment: I think this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879152/c-sharp-before-a-string

Answer (score 4):

Use a [parametrized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) instead:

```
public void InsertProjekt(string Projektbezeichnung)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=myProjekt; UID=user; PWD=pwd";
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "Insert into tblProjekte (Projektbezeichnung) values (@value)"
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", Projektbezeichnung);

    int rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

Comment: I think you forgot the '@' into the AddWithValue

Comment: @trippino it works with and without the @. I added it to follow MSDN guidelines.

Comment: ok sorry, I usually put the '@' so I thought that it was necessary

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not fix my issue, I receive the same information in SQL Server like before. I'm using SQL Server 2012 and run this function as a wcf service. I filled in my TestClient \\After tip from Stackoverflow and received \After tip from Stackoverflow. I lost a \ again.

Answer (score 3):

As several comments have pointed out, the `\` character is an "escape character" in SQL. When you're inserting it without using a properly escaped string, SQL will strip them out as it interprets them as just being escape-characters.

You're using `string.Format()` to simulate a parameterized query, and that won't really cut it. If you use [`SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx), however, it should fix your issue:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblProjekte (Projektbezeichnung) VALUES (@Projektbezeichnung)");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Projektbezeichnung", Projektbezeichnung);
com.Connection = con;
int rows = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For more information regarding `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection, check it out on the [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx). It offers a handful of 'add' methods that may be more appropriate for different scenarios - though regular `.AddWithValue()` should work fine in this case.

**update**: changed my original `.Add()` to `.AddWithValue()` as the MSDN states `SqlParameterCollection.Add()` has been deprecated in favor of `.AddWithValue()`.

Comment: Add is obsolete in your answer. It has been replaced by AddWithValue

Comment: @BasBrekelmans I literally just read that on the MSDN; I'm updating my answer now =]

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not fix my issue, I receive the same information in SQL Server like before. I'm using SQL Server 2012 and run this function as a wcf service. I filled in my TestClient \\After tip from Stackoverflow and received \After tip from Stackoverflow. I lost a \ again.