# Substring issue

Tags: c#, substring, indexof

I have the below code:

```
sDocType = pqReq.Substring(0, pqReq.IndexOf(@"\t"));
```

The string **pqReq** is like this: "CSTrlsEN\t001\t\\sgprt\Projects2\t001\tCSTrl". But even though I can clearly see the `t\` in the string, `pqReq.IndexOf(@"\t")` returns -1, so an error is thrown.

What's the correct way to do this? I don't want to split the string **pqReq** until later on in the code.

Comment: You need to be checking for \\t I believe

Comment: http://ideone.com/FghOwM

Comment: I can't reproduce this, for this input: @"CSTrlsEN\t001\t\\sgprt\Projects2\t001\tCSTrl". Check the .NET Fiddle [here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/6b0meK). Did you perhaps forget to prefix the string with `@` ?

Comment: I've tried this myself with a simple 2 liner and get back "CSTrlsEN". Are you sure that you are "@" escaping your string in code?

Comment: Is `pqReq` a literal? if it were declared inside your code, would it be declared as `pqReq = @"CSTrlsEN\t001\t\\sgprt\Projects2\t001\tCSTrl"`

Comment: In your question, you first state you are looking for `t\ `, then describe searching for `\t`.  Those are *different*.  Please clarify.

Comment: works for me. `var s = "CSTrlsEN\\t001\\t\\\\sgprt\\Projects2\\t001\\tCSTrl";` produce **exaclty** the same output as you stated, but still `s.IndexOf(@"\t")` returns **8**.

Comment: Same goes with `var s = @"CSTrlsEN\t001\t\\sgprt\Projects2\t001\tCSTrl";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Use `\\t` instead of `\t`. The `\t` is seen as a tab-character. sDocType = pqReq.Substring(0, pqReq.IndexOf(@"\t"));</s>

### Edit:

I didn't notice the `\t` being literal due to the `@`. But is your input string a literal string? If not, place an `@` before the value of `pqReq`.

```
string pqReq = @"CSTrlsEN\t001\t\\sgprt\Projects2\t001\tCSTrl";
int i = pqReq.IndexOf(@"\t");
//i = 8
```

Comment: The string is @ escaped. No escapes are possible inside this kind of string... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879152/c-sharp-before-a-string

Comment: No. The @ makes this a string literal, so `\t` is **not** escaped to a tab character. [See the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: `@"\t"` is a literal, not a tab character

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks, I was tearing my hair out as I too didn't notice the **@**

Comment: Check my edited answer, do you have an `@` before `"CSTrlsEN\t001\t\\sgprt\Projects2\t001\tCSTrl"`? If not, place one.

Comment: well, my string will come for a text file in my application so I just used that string in the question, which is how I confused everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this issue. The following code (.NET Fiddle [here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/6b0meK)):

```
var pqReq=@"CSTrlsEN\t001\t\\sgprt\Projects2\t001\tCSTrl";
var idx=pqReq.IndexOf(@"\t");
Console.WriteLine(idx);
var sDocType = pqReq.Substring(0, idx);
Console.WriteLine(sDocType);
```

produces:

```
8
CSTrlsEN
```

Did you forget to prefix pqReq with `@`?

Comment: yes that was it! In fact I only used that string literal for the question, my string will come for a text file.