# string.IndexOf ignoring escape sequences

Tags: c#, string, indexof

I'm trying to extract the CN of an LDAP DN string.

Here's an example string that illustrates the problem

```
var dn = @"CN=Firstname Lastname\, Organization,OU=some ou,DC=company,DC=com";
```

What I want is the position of the first non escaped ',' character, which is at position 32.

```
var pos = dn.IndexOf(',');
```

returns the first comma, regardless of escaping or not. Now can I bring `IndexOf` to skip the escaped comma in the string?

Comment: The '@' is making the backslash look like a regular character instead of an escape sequence.  Remove the '@'.

Comment: The string `"\,"` is not an [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences), it is just a backslash followed by a comma and it is for example printed out as-is in the console or any text box.

Comment: Also, it's better to use Regex for this sort of thing

Comment: [What is an escape sequence (M Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences)

Comment: The `@` means treat everything inside the string as [literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879175/585968).  Thus there is no _"escape sequences"_ in your string

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `\` should be escaped by *itself*: `\\` to put just `\` you can implement a simple
finite state machine

```
private static int IndexOfUnescaped(string source, 
                                    char toFind, 
                                    char escapement = '\\') {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    return -1;

  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i) 
    if (source[i] == escapement)
      i += 1; // <- skip the next (escaped) character
    else if (source[i] == toFind)
      return i;

  return -1;
}

...

var dn = @"CN=Firstname Lastname\, Organization,OU=some ou,DC=company,DC=com";

var pos = IndexOfUnescaped(dn, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex:

```
string s = @"CN=Firstname Lastname\, Organization,OU=some ou,DC=company,DC=com";
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<!\\\\),", RegexOptions.Compiled);
int firstMatch = regex.Matches(s).FirstOrDefault()?.Index ?? -1;
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Jxco8K/1

It's using a negative lookbehind, so check all commas and look if it's not preceeded by a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Colleague of mine whipped up this regex. Not entirely the question, but since I wanted the position to then use `SubString` it also does the trick.

```
var CnRegex = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z_]*)=((?:[^\\,}]|\\.)*)");
var match = CnRegex.Match(input);
if (match.Success)
    return match.Value;
return null;
```

I feared it would come down to a Regex, as in Tim's solution, or 'brute force' as with Dmitry's solution.