# @(at) sign in file path/string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, path, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the @ in front of a string for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-for-net)

I have the following code:

```
new Attachment(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + @"pdf\" + pdfItem.Value)
```

What does the `@` sign do?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It has nothing to do with filepath. It changes the escaping behavior of strings.

In a string literal prefixed with `@` the escape sequences starting with `\` are disabled. This is convenient for filepaths since `\` is the path separator and you don't want it to start an escape sequence.

In a normal string you would have to escape `\` into `\\` so your example would look like this "pdf\\". But since it's prefixed with `@` the only character that needs escaping is `"` (which is escaped as `""`) and the `\` can simply appear.

This feature is convenient for strings literals containing `\` such as filepaths or regexes.

For your simple example the gain isn't that big, but image you have a full path `"C:\\ABC\\CDE\\DEF"` then `@"C:\ABC\CDE\DEF"` looks a lot nicer.

For regular expressions it's almost a must. A regex typically contains several `\` escaping other characters already and often becomes almost unreadable if you need to escape them.

Comment: @Sally Try to run your code after removing the `@` and see the difference!

Comment: Alternatively, the `Path` class is convenient for file system paths, too.

Answer (score 30):

It's a [*verbatim string literal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

This allows the string to contain backslashes and even linebreaks without them being handled differently:

```
string multiLineString = @"First line
second line
third line";
```

As backslashes aren't used for escaping, inserting a double quote into the string requires it to be doubled:

```
string withQuote = @"before""after";
```

Verbatim string literals are typically used for file paths (as you've shown) and regular expressions, both of which frequently use backslashes.

See my [article on strings](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

It allows you to enter the backslash (\) without escaping it:

```
 var s1 = "C:\\Temp\\MyFileName";
 var s2 = @"C:\Temp\MyFileName";
```

Both result in a string with the same contents (and since strings are [interned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) at compile time, probably even the same string reference).