# parse data with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

```
<option value="28.5.2011|2">28.maj. 2 dni od 109,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="27.8.2011|2">27.avg. 2 dni od 109,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
ect
```

i need to parse data from text like this.

I need to get in first example:

109

in second example:

109

regular expression must be generic to get this data becous ei have 1000 rows.

To get 27.8.2011 i use split and | for delimeter. The same with 2. but i do not know how to get 109.

Thx

Comment: What have you tried (i.e., what does your current regex look like) and where are you stuck? The split/delimiter stuff doesn't sound like you are using regex at all at the moment...

Comment: Which of the various 2s is the 2nd regex aimed at?

Comment: I recommend using this tool to assist with creating regular expressions: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: you should make the groups in the regex the you want to fetch from data and then apply it on data by the execute method

Comment: i have only problems with 109,00. This i do not know how to get? @moon groups?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html this will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
String pat = "<option\svalue=".{1,15}?">.{1,10}?\s\d\s.{1,5}?\s.{1,5}?\s(.{1,10}?)\&nbsp\;EUR</option>";
Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.Match(test);
Group ad1 = m.Groups[1];
String out = ad1 +"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your input is strictly just the `option` markup

```
<option value="28.5.2011|2">28.maj. 2 dni od 109,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
<option value="27.8.2011|2">27.avg. 2 dni od 109,00&nbsp;EUR</option>
```

The following works:

```
"([^\|]+)\|([^"])">.*?(\d+),
```

**Note:** This is a very specific Regex and I'm not familiar with C#. So if you need exact code, someone else will have to provide it. Nonetheless, for that input, the RegEx above works.

Comment: thx for answer but i get error. So i write this: \d+((.\d+)+(,\d+)?)? Is ok?

Comment: Which error exactly? The [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) works OK with your very limited data set on [nregex.com](http://www.nregex.com) and [regexhero.net/tester](http://www.regexhero.net/tester). You probably just need to properly [take care of the quotes and escape sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179389/at-sign-in-file-path-string/5179393#5179393 "escaping behavior of strings") to use the presented string in your code…