# Why won't this string escape properly?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a string as follows, although it throws an error when it gets to the colon, I have used @ to escape everything:

```
string vmListCommand = @"vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed '1d' | awk '{if ($1 > 0) print $1":"$2}'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `@` and escape double quotes using `\`:

```
string vmListCommand = "vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed '1d' | awk '{if ($1 > 0) print $1\":\"$2}'";
```

You wrote:

> I have used @ to escape everything

`@` is used to change escaping bahaviour, not to *escape everything*. If a string is prefixed with `@` then escape sequences (`\`) are ignored.

Comment: If you want to read more about `@string` then take a look at [@(at) sign in file path/string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179389/at-sign-in-file-path-string) and [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Use `\` for escape in your string.

Example:

```
string str1 ="hello\\";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the literal and escape

```
string vmListCommand = "vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed '1d' | awk '{if ($1 > 0) print $1\":\"$2}'";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one character that needs to be escaped in literal strings. The double quote `"`. If you don't escape it, how would the compiler know which `"` are part of the string, and which terminate the string?

To escape a `"` in a literal string, simply double it:

```
 @"vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed '1d' | awk '{if ($1 > 0) print $1"":""$2}'"
```

Alternatively you could switch to the normal string syntax, and escape with `\`.