# using @ to locate file via string

Tags: c#, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@(at) sign in file path/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179389/at-sign-in-file-path-string)

in C# for example this function you can use `@"stringpath"` instead of `"stringpath"`

Why should I add an @ there in front? I get the same results without using @??

example:

```
UploadFileMethod(@"C:\test.txt", @"http://site.com/bla/file.txt");

public static bool UploadFileToDocumentLibrary(string sourceFilePath, string targetDocumentLibraryPath)

{
//stuff here
}
```

Comment: read the doco! Seriously, you could find this out yourself in minutes, if you really wanted to.

Comment: @ means a literal string, so there's no need for escaping special chars

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179389/at-sign-in-file-path-string

Comment: Placed back @Bart I did not know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes the escaping behavior of strings. When using `@` we don't need to escape `\` character.

As the path should be in this manner:

`"C:\\abc.txt"`