# Trailing backslash in C# command-line parameter: Bug or feature?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

When I give a path like `c:\some folder with a blank` into the Debug option of Visual Studio I need to escape it with a double quote `"`  just like you would on the command line as well.

If I do it like that `"c:\some folder with a blank"` then the `args[0]` parameter is `"c:\\some folder with a blank"`

However, if I do it like this `"c:\some folder with a blank\"` then the `args[0]`actually contains: `"c:\\some folder with a blank\""`, having the final `"` as an actual part of the string.

The same is true for when I call it from the command line directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\"` is an escape sequence for `"`. If you want the last backslash then use the escape sequence for the backslash `\\`

Command line argument:

```
"c:\some folder with a blank\\"
```

And because you have last `"` as an escape sequence, the argument is read till the end. If you omit `"` at the end, you still have the whole argument.

Try these arguments yourself

```
"c:\some folder with a blank\

"c:\some folder \" with a blank\
```

Comment: But if I use `"c:\temp"` then that does not mean `"c:[tab]emp"` and `"c:\audible"` does not mean `"c:[beep]udible"`

Comment: You are right, it seems like a special case, see [GetCommandLineArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#remarks)

Comment: Btw I just found the same question [Why does C# appear to partially un-escape command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359103/why-does-c-sharp-appear-to-partially-un-escape-command-line-arguments)