# SQL Server 2012 Express Silent mode Programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I am doing a silent mode SQL Server installation by running my code, This is my code:

```
string fileName, commandLine = "";

fileName = string.Format(@"{0}\SQLServer\sql64\setup.exe", setupFolder);
commandLine = string.Format(@"PCUSOURCE={0}\SQLServer\sql64 /MEDIALAYOUT=Core /CONFIGURATIONFILE={0}\SQLServer\ConfigurationFile64.ini /ACTION=Install", setupFolder);
Process.Start(fileName, commandLine);
```

It runs fine and every file is extracted from the installer, after that it pops up an error message

[image]

As you notice, I added /ACTION in the command line

> /ACTION=Install

Also I checked the configuration file and I found it.

Please help me .. this error killing me :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: A guess, its's consuming /ACTION ... as part of the configuration file path, swap them round.

Comment: Have you tried double quotes around the .ini path?

Comment: @ErikEJ I tried to put double quotes but it give me syntax mistake, Can you help me to do that please .. Thanks

Comment: The double quote is escaped as "" in your case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179389/at-sign-in-file-path-string