# Console error on executing cmd command in java

Tags: java, selenium, cmd

I am trying to execute a cmd command to crash an app from java like

```
String command = "@upwork.exe --args -url=chrome://crash  -disable-web-security -script-url=https://172.27.68.6/pre_alpha/";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

The issue is the command runs fine and crashes the app, but I get a failure

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "@upwork.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions would be of great help

Comment: @upwork.exe is not in PATH...?

Comment: looks like the command not able to find the exe location

Comment: @n00dl3: it is there

Comment: obviously it is not...

Comment: What is role of selenium here???

Comment: Is the `@` a real part of the file name or did you just add it for some reason?

Comment: @ in his path should probably be something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179389/at-sign-in-file-path-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your exception log says, `The system cannot find the file specified`

Try to give full path of `@upwork.exe` file.

Comment: and remove the @ sign?

Comment: yes, remove it and try that way

Comment: yep, it worked that way, thanks!! :)

Comment: Ok, cool, you can mark/upvote answer as correct then.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to run `@upwork.exe`, which it can't find.  Does this file exist?