# What does @"../.." mean in a path?

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

I am following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from MSDN.

There's something I saw in the code that I can't understand

```
    private void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        TreeNode rootNode;

        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"../.."); // <- What does @"../.." mean?
        if (info.Exists)
        {
            rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name);
            rootNode.Tag = info;
            GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`@` is for verbatim string, so that the string is treated as is. Especially useful for paths  that have a `\` which might be treated as escape characters ( like `\n`)

`../..`  is relative path, in this case, two levels up. `..` represents parent of current directory and so on.

Answer (score 8):

`..` is the container directory. So `../..` means "up" twice.
For example if your current directory is `C:/projects/a/b/c` then `../..` will be `C:/projects/a`

Comment: Not the downvoter but `.` represents the current directory and `..` would be one level up, maybe someone was upset reading your first line and hence voted you down

Comment: Pretty sure it's because the OP *knows* what ../.. means; he didn't know what @ means. It's the combination that threw him off, especially because the @ is redundant here anyway.

Answer (score 4):

example E:\Software\file\folder

/ is the root of the current drive.
./ is the current director.
../ is the parent of the current directory. that is ->E:\ ../.. is relative path, in this case, two levels up.
to get folder just write "../../folder"

Answer (score 3):

`new DirectoryInfo(@"../..")` means "a directory two levels above the current one".

The `@` denotes a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).