# How do I escape a RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex that I now need to moved into C#.  I'm getting errors like this

```
Unrecognized escape sequence
```

I am using Regex.Escape -- but obviously incorrectly.

```
string pattern = Regex.Escape("^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*(\d|[!@#$%\?\(\)\*\&\^\-\+\=_])).*$");
hiddenRegex.Attributes.Add("value", pattern);
```

How is this correctly done?

Comment: `Regex.Escape` is to escape special characters in a regex pattern so they match verbatim in the input.

Comment: error of ESCAPE is for LANGUAGE COMPILE. \ is need for ESCAPE in STRING. not just REGEX !! MUST escape with \ or use @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is due to the fact that your string contains invalid escape sequences (e.g. `\d`). To fix this, either escape the backslashes manually or write a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) instead:

```
string pattern = @"^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*(\d|[!@#$%\?\(\)\*\&\^\-\+\=_])).*$";
```

`Regex.Escape` would be used when you want to embed dynamic content to a regular expression, not when you want to construct a fixed regex. For example, you would use it here:

```
string name = "this comes from user input";
string pattern = string.Format("^{0}$", Regex.Escape(name));
```

You do this because `name` could very well include characters that have special meaning in a regex, such as dots or parentheses. When `name` is hardcoded (as in your example) you can escape those characters manually.

Answer (score 4):

The error you're getting is coming at compile time correct? That means C# compiler is not able to make sense of your string. Prepend @ sign before the string and you should be fine. You don't need Regex.Escape.

See [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*(\d|[!@#$%\?\(\)\*\&\^\-\+\=_])).*$");
pattern.IsMatch("Your input string to test the pattern against");
```