# Why do we use @ with "\" while trying to replace it with another string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

why do we use `@` to replace `\` with another string using `string.replace(@"\","$$")`
i'm using `C#` windows application

Comment: erm, guess what, this came up before at lease once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c

Comment: Its also simple to get an answer using google http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%23+%40+string+literal&oq=c%23+%40&gs_l=hp.3.3.0l4.1984.3609.0.7375.4.4.0.0.0.0.157.438.2j2.4.0...0.0...1c.WrAiSY5d3aY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=9136b82e38d1314b&biw=1280&bih=841

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@` in front of a string literal makes it a [*verbatim string literal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), so the backslash `\` does not need to be doubled. You can use `"\\"` instead of `@"\"` for the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Because if you didn't, you'd have to escape `\` with `\\`

`@` is used to what's called [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you can prefix a string with `@` to make it verbatim, so you don't need to escape special characters.

```
@"\"
```

is identical to

```
"\\"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [C# Language Specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) 2.4.4.5 String literals states:

> C# supports two forms of string literals: regular string literals and
>   verbatim string literals.
>
> A regular string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed
>   in double quotes, as in "hello", and may include both simple escape
>   sequences (such as \t for the tab character), and hexadecimal and
>   Unicode escape sequences.
>
> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a
>   double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing
>   double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim
>   string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted
>   verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In
>   particular, simple escape sequences, and hexadecimal and Unicode
>   escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A
>   verbatim string literal may span multiple lines.

The verbatim string literal, which uses the `@` character, makes it a little easier in practicality to escape almost all the characters that you would otherwise have to escape individually with the `\` character in a string.

Note: the `"` char will still require escaping even with the verbatim mode.

So I would use it to save time from having to go through a long string to escape all the necessary characters that needed escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Because the backslash is treated as an escape character and you would get an 'Unrecognised escape sequence' error if you didn't use '@'. Using '@' tells the compiler to ignore escape characters. [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hirendra_singh/verbatim-strings-in-C-Sharp-use-of-symbol-in-string-literals/) may be helpful.