# Why assign a string with @?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

This is something I have questioned for a long time but never bothered to figure out.  When I download third party libraries I have often seen string assignments using a `@` symbol before the string.

```
string myString = @"Some text";
```

But there seems to be absolutely no difference if I simply do

```
string myString = "Some text";
```

So what is the `@` doing?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that when I was searching.

Comment: @michael.mankus well how much "research" did you do then? I remember looking for it when I didn't know what it meant and finding it in seconds...

Comment: In all fairness, I did a google search (https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=what+does+the+%40+do+in+c%23) and none of the links on the first page of results even address the issue.  I thought it seemed to be a fair enough question.  But if you feel the need to downvote, it's okay.  And as I said, I am sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I might say that your Google search wasn't well written. The @ in C# can be anything, if you simply add the word "string" the result pops up very quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is signifies a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and allows you to *not* have to escape certain characters:

```
string foo = @"c:\some\path\filename.exe";
```

vs:

```
string foo = "c:\\some\\path\\filename.exe";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string reason = @"this string literal mea\ns something different with an @ in front than without";
```

Without the @, the above string would have a new-line character instead of an 'n' in the word "means". With the @, the word "means" looks just like you see it. This feature is especially useful for things like file paths:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\LookMa\NoDoubleSlashes.txt";
```

Comment: And what is that difference?  That is the question after all?

Comment: +1 for answering the question with only self-documenting code.

Answer (score 1):

It is a verbatim string literal.  It lets you do things like `@"C:\"` instead of `"C:\\"`, and is especially useful in regex and file paths, since these often use backslashes that shouldn't be parsed by the compiler.  See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is no difference.
All '@' does is allow you to omit escape backslashes.  If you use '@' and want in include double quotes in the string you need to double up the double quotes.