# Calling a javascript function with parameter bound to repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net, parameters, repeater

I'm trying to call a javascript function.

```
function callSubClass(SubClassName) {
  ...
}
```

But I am trying to call it inside a repeater where the parameter "SubClassName" is a string bound to my repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSubClass" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("SubClassName") %>' runat="server" ID="linkHomeItem" OnClick='<%# callSubClass(Eval("SubClassName")); return false; %>'/>
    <br />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But every time I run it I get a compiler error saying:

> CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line Error

Now I know the error is on the OnClick='stuff' but I've tried all I could think of to make it work. Here's a list of what I tried so far.

```
OnClick='<%# callSubClass(Eval("SubClassName")); return false; %>'
OnClick='callSubClass(<%# Eval("SubClassName") %>); return false;'
OnClick='"callSubClass("+<%# Eval("SubClassName") %>+"); return false;"'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Like this...Instead of `Onclick` use `OnClientClick` to run javascript code.....

```
OnClientClick='<%# @"callSubClass("""+Eval("SubClassName").ToString()+@""");return false;" %>'
```

Comment: It works thank you. :) But can you explain me the part with the @" " please?

Comment: @snaplemouton @ is used in string to escape the sqequence and to include double quote you in your string.. have to write @"""" it will print " like this here is link which explain in technical term http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c

Comment: @snaplemouton welcone always