# File.Exists yields false, but the file exists

Tags: c#

I have a strange issue using File.Exists in C#, reproducable on several PC's. I see it as an error in the .NET 4 library.

I use 7ZIP and automate it from a C# program, I call CreateProcess and zip and unzip files with it. For that, I need to find out if and where 7ZIP is installed, because I don't want to depend on PATH variables.

So this is part of the code:

```
if (File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"))
    clsGlobal.gstr_ZIP_PROG_MIT_PFAD = "\"" + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\"";

else if (File.Exists("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\""))
    clsGlobal.gstr_ZIP_PROG_MIT_PFAD = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\"";
```

All Exist-Checks give me "false" back. The ProgramFiles-SpecialFolder points to the right (x86)-Folder, for sure. And also for sure, 7ZIP is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\7-ZIP\7z.exe, and when calling CreateProcess, everything works fine. What can be the reason why all Exists() - Checks fail ? Is this a known bug ?

Comment: For the second, try removing the surrounding `\"`'s.

Comment: Just a thought: Please use Verbatim literal "@" to make your code readable

Comment: [To expand on @nowhewhomustnotbenamed.'s comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

I would say that Dukeling is correct in his comment

```
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe\""
```

is looking for a path starting with the double quotes BEFORE the C:\
As now he who must not be named said use the "@" before the string so it becomes:

@"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe\"

This makes the code readable and also prevents any confusion with quotes which seems to be what is happening here.

Answer (score 2):

> I see it as an error in the .NET 4 library.

This is not a bug in the .NET Framework...

Print the path value.

It will be:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe

By default i believe `7-Zip` installs to `Program Files` and not `Program Files (x86)`.

You are using:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles
```

If your code is built to target x86 (i suspect it is) then this enum will give you:

> Program Files (x86)

[System.EnvironmentSpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

> The program files directory.On a non-x86 system, passing ProgramFiles to the GetFolderPath method returns the path for non-x86 programs. To get the x86 program files directory on a non-x86 system, use the ProgramFilesX86 member.

Which is not the folder that `7-Zip` installs to.

If you change your code to read:

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.sfx"))
```

You should be fine

Alternatively, target `x64` and the enum will return the `Program Files` string:

[image: config]

The path will now read:

> C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe