# Asp.net mvc display name attribute with @

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I used resharper for my asp.net mvc application to format code and it changed all my code with @ in DisplayName attribute. I tried searching for this in google to find out what @ does here but I cant find satisfactory search result. COuld some on tell me about the difference between with and with out @ in displayname attribute.

```
[DisplayName("Meeting Date")]
[DisplayName(@"Meeting Date")]
```

Comment: It doesn't modify the attribute but rather modifies how the string is interpreted.  `@` indicates not to escape characters in the string.  In the specific example you show, it won't make any difference, but it allows you to have backslashes in your strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that this is being done in an attribute is immaterial.  Using the '@' character in front of a string literal is called a verbatim string and causes any escape sequence to be ignored, allowing you to do this:

```
var filename = @"C:\Filename.ext"
```

instead of this:

```
var filename = "C:\\Filename.ext"
```

Lots of people like that because it is prettier.  Resharper likes to put that '@' symbol in front of string literals.

As I recall Resharper suggests you either move localizable strings into a resource file or make them verbatim.  In your case, it looks like you accepted the suggestion (either explicitly or via code cleanup) to make a string verbatim.  You can turn off the verbatim string suggestion under Resharper --> Options --> Code Editing --> C# --> Context Actions --> Convert to verbatim string.

Actually, I'm NOT sure why ReSharper would have detected an Attribute constructor value as localizable since they must be compile-time constant, so it probably did that based on some other condition.  A quick email to [support@jetbrains.com](http://mailtp%3asupport@jetbrains.com) should get that sorted out for you pretty quickly.

**NOTE:** The '@' symbol can also be used in front of a reserved word in order to use that as a variable name, though this is not the case in your example above:

```
var @string = "string";
```

Comment: It should also be mentioned that in addition to ignoring escape sequences and allowing use of reserved words, it allows you to span multiple lines without concatenation.

Comment: @Justin, technically this falls under the category of allowing characters that usually need to be escaped with \.  In this case, it will allow a literal newline in your string rather than the usual \n.