# regex to replace self closing html tags in c#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have an xml which contains some html tags also. When a  tag comes in, it breaks the page because it's a self closing tag. Something like:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/6krfYKxJFqA" frameborder="0" />
```

I want to replace this and convert it to:

Can anyone provide a c# code with regex to do this. I tried doing:

```
tmp = tmp.Replace("(<iframe[^>]*)(\\s*/>)", "$1></iframe>");
```

and

```
tmp = new Regex(@"(<iframe[^>]*)(\\s*/>)").Replace(tmp, "$1></iframe>");
```

tmp is the xml containing lot of code + this iframe tag as string.

but with no result.

Comment: In the second regex, you don't need the double backslash as you are using `@`

Comment: Bravo.. Thanks. That was the problem. Just for knowledge, what difference does @ cause?

Comment: Sure. Posted as an answer please accept.

Comment: [These things can be harder than they look](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second regex, you don't need the double backslash as [you are using `@`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c).

Also, `(<iframe[^>]*)` also matches the last `/`, use the non-greedy `?` operator: `(<iframe[^>]*?)(\s*/>)`

Comment: How do I completely remove the iframe tags if I want to?

Comment: @RossCooper Use `<iframe[^>]*>` and replace it with an empty string `""`

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a match expression:

```
<iframe(.*?)(["\d\w\s])\/>
```

note that you can use http://regexpal.com/ to test regex, it's super convenient.