# Python photo browsing variable passing

Tags: c#, python, webcam

I am doing a webcam project and i tried to use c# to run a python script with a location variable passed to python so i can keep changing the opening/saving location of the images.

This is used to pass the location of the opening of image to do a cropping.

```
string loca = File.ReadAllText("cropface.py").Replace("%location%", "C:\\Users\\L31101\\Desktop\\Camera\\Camera\\bin\\Debug\\center\\center.jpg");
            File.WriteAllText("cropface.py", loca);
```

However my python script receive the location without 2 backslash

```
image =  Image.open("C:\Users\L31101\Desktop\Camera\Camera\bin\Debug\center\center.jpg")
```

Therefore, i tried passing forward slash instead of 2 backslash however my python script still receive 1 backslash.

Any idea how to go around it?

Comment: Instead of `"C:\\Users\\L31101\\Desktop\\Camera\\Camera\\bin\\Debug\\center\\center.jpg");` try `@"C:\\Users\\L31101\\Desktop\\Camera\\Camera\\bin\\Debug\\center\\center.jpg");`. Then two backslashed will be passed.

Comment: fell free to accept the anwser if helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

`"C:\\Users\\L31101\\Desktop\\Camera\\Camera\\bin\\Debug\\center\\center.jpg";`

try

`@"C:\\Users\\L31101\\Desktop\\Camera\\Camera\\bin\\Debug\\center\\center.jpg";`.

Then two backslashed will be passed.

More [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Thanks again to the help!