# copy a file to a table in postgresql using C# npgsql driver and how to get a single \ when using path names

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am trying to a copy tab delimited text file to postgresql in c# from the E drive of a server.

My sql command

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("COPY scrap (gl_post_date,stock_number,stock_description,reason_code,adjusted_qty,unit_cost,extended_cost,week,cost,catch_all) from" + FileName + ";", conn);
```

Here is my path code

```
string r = @"E:\";
            string t = txtFileName.Text;
            FileName = r + t;
```

I check my filename variable and it returns the path with a double backslash I need it to return E:\file.txt

What am I doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# a backslash in a string has a special meaning, for example `\n` is a new line, `\t` is a tab... and `\\` is actually a backslash. These combinations of a backslash and a character are called escape sequences. However, in your example you used so called verbatim string literal. @ at the beginning of a string means that a backslash within a string should be treated as any other character (it disables escape sequences). In other words `@"E:\"` is the same thing as `"E:\\"` and it is ok. For more details see also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) article and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c) question.

I also suggest to use `Path.Combine` method in order to join the drive name with the file name in the reliable way.

Comment: How do I put Path.Combine(r, t) in single quotes in the sql statement? Postgresql only allows the path to be in single quotes 'E:\file.txt using pgadmin query builder. How can I achieve single quotes around variables in C# sql statements?

Comment: Did you try to run this code? I think it should work because as I wrote above \\ = \. If it doesn't work tell me what error/exception is actually reported.

Comment: I dont get any errors, but the data from the file will not copy to the table. I run the query in pgAdmin but the data has not been added. I put my import method in a try catch but it goes through with no errors.

Comment: I had a noob moment I need to put the single quotes in double quotes then combine it

Comment: I'm not sure what effect you exactly want achieve but try var s = "\"'\""; what is the same thing as var s = @"""'""";