# Works perfectly except changes are not saved to the SQL database

Tags: c#, executenonquery

Changes are not saved to the SQL database

Why would I want to use '@' in the sql statement instead of the way that I have the statement?

Code:

```
    private void button_Save_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqlString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlString);

        try
        {
            string customer_Ship_ID = customer_Ship_IDTextBox.ToString();
            string customer_Ship_Address = customer_Ship_AddressTextBox.Text;
            SQL = "UPDATE Customer_Ship SET Customer_Ship_Address = customer_Ship_Address WHERE Customer_Ship_ID = customer_Ship_ID";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Customer_Ship_ID", customer_Ship_ID);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Customer_Ship_Address", customer_Ship_Address);
            sqlCommand.CommandText = SQL;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
```

Comment: See [the fabulous MSDN docs on the `UPDATE` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) to get your syntax right ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can check the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) for the `update` command.

Use parameters, [Why?](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Also check that you need to open and close the connection object, not the command.

In case you want to update the rows with the Customer_ID = "something" you could do like this:

The code *(updated after your changes)*:

```
private void button_Save_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sqlString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlString);
    try
    {
        int customer_Ship_ID;
        if(int.TryParse(customer_Ship_IDTextBox.Text, out customer_Ship_ID))
        {
            string customer_Ship_Address = customer_Ship_AddressTextBox.Text;
            // Customer_Ship: Database's table
            // Customer_Ship_Address, Customer_Ship_ID: fields of your table in database
            // @Customer_Ship_Address, @Customer_Ship_ID: parameters of the sqlcommand
            // customer_Ship_ID, customer_Ship_Address: values of the parameters
            string SQL = "UPDATE Customer_Ship SET Customer_Ship_Address = @Customer_Ship_Address WHERE Customer_Ship_ID = @Customer_Ship_ID";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, sqlConnection);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Customer_Ship_ID", customer_Ship_ID);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Customer_Ship_Address", customer_Ship_Address);
            sqlCommand.CommandText = SQL;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            // The id of the textbox is not an integer...
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  I have changed my original code above showing what I have now.  I don't get any error messages but the changes are not made to the database.  also, why use '@' for the sql statement instead of the way that I have it originally?

Comment: For the @: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c
does your table contain a customer_id with same value of the where in the update statement?

Comment: Check again your code with my answer.
Your are missing the '@' for the parameters. The @ tells what should be replaced with the value: @"UPDATE Customer_Ship SET Customer_Ship_Address = @Customer_Ship_AddressTextBox WHERE Customer_ID = @Customer_IDTextBox"; Also uncomment the parameter for the customer_id and change the open to use the sqlConnection.Open() instead of the command

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look and verify you have the same code.

Comment: customer_id question is yes, the datatable has Customer_ID and the text box on the form is named customer_IDTextBox. I should probably be using Customer_Ship_ID because its the key field.  the Customer_ID in the Customer_Ship datatable is to connect to the customer name in Customer datatable.  eventually I will have a one to many due to multiple locations.  checking the other code now.  thanks very much for the help

Comment: ok, did everything  you wanted me to do including the uncomment the parameter for the customer_id. I am not tying to change the customer_id just the Customer_Ship_Address.  now I get an error 'Must declare the scalar variable"customer_Ship_AddressTextBox.

Comment: Check the SQL string carefully... The names with the @ at the beginning should appear with the same name in the parameters.addwithvalue

Comment: I get an error, cant convert cusomter_Ship_ID to int.  before this error it appeared to work properly but the change to Customer_Ship_Address would not save to the sql datatable

Comment: Ok, try now. The code will try to parse the textbox with the id to an integer. Make sure you write a valid Id.

Comment: Thanks very much, i have been battling this for 3 months(i am a complete newby at C# and appreciate the help. I didn't use the complete IF statement i just used "int.TryParse(customer_Ship_IDTextBox.Text, out customer_Ship_ID)". now i just need to add the rest of the columns to the SQL statement and the AddWithValue for each column.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your syntax isn't correct. Here's the syntax for the `Update`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

So, Update, what to set, and WHERE to set (which you seem to be missing).

For more, have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Answer (score -3):

Check your update query

Change it like

```
string SQL = string.format("UPDATE Customer_Ship SET Customer_Ship_Address='{0}'",putUrVaue);
```