# C# Edit XML, I am totally lost

Tags: c#, xml

I have this code to Load xml files that I am not sure of if it is complete. This is my code.

```
public void updateXML(string xmlFile, string chooseNode, string chooseSingleNode, string newNode, string selectedCategory)
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(xmlFile);

    foreach (XmlElement element in xml.SelectNodes(chooseNode))
    {
        foreach (XmlElement element1 in element)
        {
            if (element.SelectSingleNode(chooseNode).InnerText == selectedCategory)
            {

                XmlNode newvalue = xml.CreateElement(newNode);
                newvalue.InnerText = "MODIFIED";
                element.ReplaceChild(newvalue, element1);

                xml.Save(xmlFile);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the method that I use in the end, where I set xmlfile and such. (the updateXML method is in "data.cs", which is called on from the repository.

```
public void editCategory(string newNode)
{
    string xmlFile = "Category.xml";
    string chooseNodes = "ArrayOfCategory/Category";
    string chooseSingleNode = "//Name";
    string selectedCategory = "News";

    repository.Update(xmlFile, chooseNodes, newNode, chooseSingleNode, selectedCategory);
}
```

I am unsure of what to put in the diffrent Nodes etc, the code above I found here on Stackoverflow.
- Below is my XMLfile that I want to edit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfCategory xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Category>
        <Id>6b30511d-2cd1-4325-ad73-7b905f76ffc0</Id>
        <Name>News</Name>
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <Id>516401f4-b45c-46ef-b8f4-9d05021ae794</Id>
        <Name>Pods</Name>
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <Id>0c9cd216-86cf-4a62-884c-1b428150ebac</Id>
        <Name>Pods</Name>
    </Category>
</ArrayOfCategory>
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: So what is your question? And you shouldnt save your xml file in the foreach, just save it in the end

Comment: well, It is not working.. I am doing somehow writing the wrong references , as an example //name and such. I tried to solve it but it always gets stuck in the if-statement.

Comment: Questions without a clear problem statement have no value to future readers here. Please [edit] your question to make it clear what problem you're having with the code above and ask a specific question that can be answered. (Don't include it in a comment - [edit] your question to include the information there.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (element.SelectSingleNode(chooseNode).InnerText == selectedCategory)
```

> ChooseNode = "ArrayOfCategory/Category"

```
selectedCategory = "News";
```

So the innertext of chooseNode will never be "News" because "News" is under `<Name>`

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong in your second `foreach` : did you forget to put `element.SelectNodes` or something ?

Next thing: you can modify an XmlElement directly, no need to create a new one. You create (and add it) only if it's not there.

I strongly recommend you have a look at the MSDN documentation of XmlDocument, more specifically `CreateElement` and [this simple example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hcebdtae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) following the `SelectNodes` presentation.

Moreover, you may want to consider putting an `@` in front of your strings :
see [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)