# Uploading a file that is stored on the internet - "path is not absolute" error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Selenium test running with ChromeDriver, that uploads a video file by using SendKeys to provide a path to the file element, circumventing the dialog box.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("videoFile")).SendKeys("C:\src\TestFiles\testvideo.mp4");
```

I'm in the process of moving our build boxes to the cloud to save time/money/effort, but this means that using locally-stored files is no longer sustainable, so I've moved them to a website.

I've tried to replace the local path with the full http path, but am getting the below error

```
error: unknown error: path is not absolute: https://example.cloudfront.net/999/testvideo.mp4
```

This process works when I do it manually through the dialog box, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("videoFile")).SendKeys(@"string filepath");
```

`@` marks the string as a verbatim string literal - anything in the string that would normally be interpreted as an escape sequence is ignored.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)
[image]

Comment: Just tried this and got the same error as before. It doesn't seem to be trying to escape the string as the error message identifies it in full.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of using `SendKeys()`