# The specified network name is no longer available?

Tags: c#, mp4, nancy

I want to play a local video file from nancy embedded http server. It is OK to read a txt file but once it tries to open a video file it gives error :

> "The specified network name is no longer available"

on the line

```
return Response.AsStream(() => File.OpenRead(@"E:\test_videos\test.mp4"), "video/mp4");
```

I can play the video from my browser, so what is wrong then?

Update: I could play video on FireFox and IE, the error only occurs in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented mp4handler for nancyfx and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set a [static convention](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content), and serve the files directly without passing them trough nancy.

Answer (score -2):

Your backslashes are probably getting filtered out of existence, try replacing '\' with '\ \', (no space in there) otherwise looks ok to me

Comment: He is using @"~..." so the '\' are ignored.

Comment: The @ sign in @"E:\test_videos\test.mp4" ensures you don't need to escape - in this case - slashes anymore. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c

Comment: yes, it is not about '\' since it is working on txt.files like =>  File.OpenRead(@"E:\test.txt")