# What's the $ modifier of a C# string

Tags: c#, .net, string

This question sounds similar to this:

[What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

But I'm already aware of the meaning of the @-character in front of a string literal in C#.

However now I've seen this in an example:

```
var xml = $@"<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>text</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>

    <audio src='ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm10' loop='true'/>
</toast>";
```

There is an additional $ coming with the @. What does this mean?

Comment: Although it does use the string interpolation modifier, it doesn't actually use string interpolation at all.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yes, but I guess that was my mistake since I dind't realize how it works. I tried a string.format afterwards and it failed. Before posting the question I removed my {0} from the text tag, because I thought that would be another problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's `interpolated string`, a new feature for C# 6.0 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx)

Basically, it replace `string.Format("", params);` in old C# version

Example usage:

```
var str = "test";
var xml = $@"<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
            <text>{str}</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
    <audio src='ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm10' loop='true'/>
</toast>";
```

Comment: Okay, I see. My question should then really be about $ not @$, since they are not connected. Maybe that's the reason, I haven't found the information...

Answer (score 1):

The `$` sign denotes an interpolated string in C#.

MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Usage example:

```
string zzz = "world";
string helloWorld = $"hello {zzz}"; // hello world
```

There are no curly braces inside the string in your code, so no actual value injection occurs - you can remove the `$` and still get identical results.