# C# If regex doesn't match then do something

Tags: c#, regex

So I got piece of code, which works like if someone writes in chat !buy 3, then Regex gets that number 3 and does stuff, but how could I make code that if someone just types !buy, then it tells "him" something, else than throwing error to console because there were no number.

```
var getinfo = message.ToString();
Regex getInfo = new Regex("[0-9]+");
var random3 = getInfo.Match(getinfo).Value;
```

Comment: Could we see your regex, and the code that does this, to at least provide comment on?

Comment: Is there even a reason to use regex? If your command always comes first and the command doesn't have space(!Buy, !Sell, !View_Bag or !ViewBag) you could simple split it by space and read the first entry/check how many non-empty entries you have for providing an reply for empty commands.

Comment: I've edited first post

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string getinfo = message.ToString();
Regex regex = new Regex("[0-9]+");
Match match = regex.Match(getinfo);
//if regex doesn't match
if (!match.Success)
{
    //do something.
}
```

Comment: What's that `@` in the beginning of your pattern?

Comment: @Shafizadeh [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Hmm, you're code would be great, but throws me that error actually: ERROR: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: I've updated my answer for your example.