# DataGrid Column Binding with Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need help in binding a Dictionary to a wpf DataGrid Column:

**What is working?**

A Dictionary with int as key (`Dictionary<int, Object>`) works with the following binding path

```
dgtc1.Binding = new Binding("ResourceDic1[0].Name");
```

**What is not working?**

A Dictionary with int as key (`Dictionary<String, Object>`) is not working with the following binding path and I need help in getting this binding working:

```
dgtc1.Binding = new Binding("ResourceDic1["Name_100"].Name");
```

**Here is the code to reproduce the issue:**

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="DataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="3" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Name="DataGrid2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Code MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace DataGridBinding
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Project> Projects = new List<Project>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Project pj = new Project();
                for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    pj.ResourceDic1.Add(k, new PResource(String.Format("Name_{0}", 100 + k), 100 + k, 0.25));
                    pj.ResourceDic2.Add(String.Format("Name_{0}", 100 + k), new PResource(String.Format("Name_{0}", 100 + k), 100 + k, 0.25));
                }
                Projects.Add(pj);
            }

            DataGrid1.ItemsSource = Projects;
            DataGridTextColumn dgtc1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            dgtc1.Header = "Binding1";
            //////////////////////
            //This binding works//
            //////////////////////
            dgtc1.Binding = new Binding("ResourceDic1[0].Name");
            DataGrid1.Columns.Add(dgtc1);
            DataGrid1.Items.Refresh();

            DataGrid2.ItemsSource = Projects;
            DataGridTextColumn dgtc2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            dgtc2.Header = "Binding2";
            /////////////////////////////
            //This binding doesn't work//
            /////////////////////////////
            dgtc2.Binding = new Binding(@"ResourceDic2[""Name_100""].Name");
            DataGrid2.Columns.Add(dgtc2);
            DataGrid2.Items.Refresh();
        } 
    }
}
```

The Code Project.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataGridBinding
{
    public class Project
    {
        public Dictionary<int, PResource> ResourceDic1 { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<String, PResource> ResourceDic2 { get; set; }

        public Project()
        {
            ResourceDic1 = new Dictionary<int, PResource>();
            ResourceDic2 = new Dictionary<string, PResource>();
        }
    }
}
```

The Code PResource.cs:

```
using System;

namespace DataGridBinding
{
    public class PResource
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }

        public PResource(String Name, int Number, double Value)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Number = Number;
            this.Value = Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**How do I need to structure the binding path so that it works?**

```
dgtc2.Binding = new Binding(@"ResourceDic2[""Name_100""].Name");
```

Comment: Did you just try `dgtc2.Binding = new Binding(@"ResourceDic2[Name_100].Name");`?

Comment: @Sam, indeed it worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my comment: try `dgtc2.Binding = new Binding(@"ResourceDic2[Name_100].Name");`

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
{
    pj.ResourceDic1.Add(k, new PResource(String.Format("Name_{0}", 100 + k), 100 + k, 0.25));
    pj.ResourceDic2.Add(String.Format("Name_{0}", 100 + k), new PResource(String.Format("Name_{0}", 100 + k), 100 + k, 0.25));
}
```

You are adding:

- [0]: PResource object **|||** "Name_100" : PResource object
- [1]: PResource object **|||** "Name_101" : PResource object
- [2]: PResource object **|||** "Name_102" : PResource object
- [3]: PResource object **|||** "Name_103" : PResource object
- [4]: PResource object **|||** "Name_104" : PResource object

`Name_1` key does not exist in `ResourceDic2`.

Comment: Thank your for pointing the mistake, even after fixing it, it doesn't work and I've updated the question based on your answer.

Comment: @Abbas I would also want to point out that you didn't set the `ItemsSource` for `DataGrid2`.

Comment: @Abbas And the escape character for `"` is `\ `, which means you should use `\"`.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing the mistakes again, I'm sorry for not noticing it earlier, unfortunately fixing them still doens't work. And w.r.t escape character in "vertabtim string literal" escape character for `"` is another `"`, you can find more details in http://stackoverflow.com/q/556133/1437877