# How to bind Windows DataGridView to nested object (dictionary)?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

we have datagridview which is bound to an object(fiddler core)
now this object as disctionart oflags
We are not able to bind oflags to a datagridView but are able to bind other fields. We are using datagridview in C# that has as request id, url and oflag[“Deviation”] values
Can you please send any sample code that can be used to bind Oflags

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "id";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "id";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "id";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "fullUrl";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "fullUrl";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "fullUrl";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "LocalProcess";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "LocalProcess";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "LocalProcess";
dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "oFlags";
dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "oFlags";
**dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "oFlags[Deviation]";**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataGrid Column Binding with Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449597/datagrid-column-binding-with-dictionary)

Comment: If you have a “collection” of objects, and you set the `DataGridView.DataSource` to this collection of objects, then each publicly exposed property of that object will be translated to a column in the grid. This works for primitive and single value properties, HOWEVER, IF one of the publicly exposed properties of the object is another Class or “collection" (like a dictionary), then those properties will NOT have a column generated because those properties are “collections” and the grid is not smart enough to flatted the collection into a single value to display in a single cell.

Comment: Basically the grid does not know how to put “multiple” items into a single cell. One possible solution is to create another property in the object that returns a flattened version of the collection. Then the grid will automatically create a column for that property. Another solution is to create a Master-Detail scenario with two grids. The first grid shows the objects in each row and the other grid would display the `oFlags` for the selected object in the first grid (Master-detail). Sorry if I am missing something.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Set AutoGenerateColumns False

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

//Set Columns Count

dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

//Add Columns

dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "CustomerId";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Customer Id";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "CustomerID";
 
dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Contact Name";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Name";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ContactName";
 
dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Country";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Country";
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Country";
```

See also [Bind data to DataGridView in Windows Forms Application in C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-data-to-DataGridView-in-Windows-Forms-Application-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx).

Comment: this does not solve my program as oflag is dictionary,
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "oFlags[Deviation]"