# Splitting a string in the format domain\alias

Tags: c#

I have a user input variable containing the string in the format: `"domain\alias"` and I need to split this in two different strings: domain and alias.

I heard somewhere about conversion of strings to literals but I don't understand how that will help me here.

Comment: `doamin` --> `domain` typo? Can you show an example?

Comment: Here is the example. and yes that was a typo.
my variable is say xyz. containing a string in the form of domain\alias.
now i want to split xyz in two different strings: domain and alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = @"domain\alias";
int inputindex=  input.IndexOf("\\");           
string domain = input.Substring(0, inputindex);
string alias = input.Substring(inputindex+1);
```

Comment: This will throw if the input doesn't contain a backslash (`\ `), because then `IndexOf()` will return -1.

Comment: Yes.But the question asked by @dotnetman doesnt specify this exception.Does it?

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
var x = @"doamin\alias".Split('\\')
```

it will give you an array whith contents

```
x[0] = "doamin"
x[1] = "alias"
```

if you want to get user even if domain isn't specified:

```
var user = x.Length == 2 ? x[1] : x[0];
var domain = x.Length == 2 ? x[0] : null;
```

Comment: thanks. but say I have a string in a variable xyz then the above method doesn't work..please suggest.

Comment: Infact, it doesn't work in the above case as well, unless and until I prefix '@' to the string.

Comment: Well `@"domain\alias"` is *exactly* the same as writing `"domain\\alias"`. If we put the `@` in front of the string we don't have to escape the backslash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c