# Main method compiles only when it's empty

Tags: c#, console-application

I have created the following program:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public enum MyEnum { Jan = 1, Feb = 2, Mar = 3, Apr = 4, May = 5, Jun = 6, Jul = 7, Aug = 8, Sep = 9, Okt = 10, Nov = 11, Dec = 12 }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            private static string sourcePath = @"T:\his\is\my\source";
            private static string destinationPath = @"T:\his\is\my\destination";
        }
    }
}
```

That's all I have so far. The problem is that it doesn't compile like this. I get the following exception:

> } expected

It only works when I leave the `Main` method body empty. When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to format the code, it is formatted like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public enum MyEnum { SomeField = 1, SomeOtherField = 2, ... }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            private static string sourcePath = @"T:\his\is\my\source";
        private static string destinationPath = @"T:\his\is\my\destination";
    }
}
}
```

This totally doesn't make any sense. I can't even access the parameter `args`:

> The name 'args' does not exist in the current context

I really don't know why my project is behaving like this. Did anyone else encounter the same problem? What should I do?

Comment: Could it be this line?  `public enum MyEnum { SomeField = 1, SomeOtherField = 2, ... }`.  Do you actually have it like that?   Get rid of the ellipsis and put actual values.

Comment: No, even when I remove the enum, I'm getting the same exception.

Comment: @rory.ap Erm, that is the question! ;p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot declare the class fields inside a method.
Move the following lines out of it:

```
private static string sourcePath = @"T:\his\is\my\source";
private static string destinationPath = @"T:\his\is\my\destination";
```

Or if you want these variables to be local for the method, declare them as:

```
string sourcePath = @"T:\his\is\my\source";
string destinationPath = @"T:\his\is\my\destination";
```

Comment: And it will still fail...

Comment: Thank you, it works now.

Comment: `@"T:\h..."` add `@`, please

Comment: Also make the strings `const`.

Comment: @Bauss: these strings are not necessary `constant`s

Comment: Why would changing to const, solve the problem?? What's the logic in that?

Comment: @Renato Afonso: `private static string sourcePath...` is attempt to declare a *field* within a *method* which is syntax error (*field* can be declared within `class`/`struct` only); `const string sourcePath...` is just a *constant* (compare with `string sourcePath...` whcih is just a *variable*) which is perfectly legal.

Comment: Note that as @DmitryBychenko comments this is not the only problem with the above code that will cause it to fail to compile, see my answer for more details

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have copied the code directly, you have three main mistakes. Firstly in your enum you have some ellipses at the end:

```
public enum MyEnum { SomeField = 1, SomeOtherField = 2, ... }
```

You need to remove them and if necessary put in more values.

Secondly you are trying to declare what look like fields inside of you `Main` method. You need to move them out of the method:

```
private static string sourcePath = "T:\his\is\my\source";
private static string destinationPath = "T:\his\is\my\destination";

static void Main(string[] args)
{

}
```

Or make them method level variables by removing the access level modifiers and the static modifier:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sourcePath = "T:\his\is\my\source";
    string destinationPath = "T:\his\is\my\destination";
}
```

Finally your paths are constructed like so:

```
"T:\his\is\my\source"
```

Here you have back slashes which in C# strings are used to create escape sequences. You need to either escape them with another back slash:

```
"T:\\his\\is\\my\\source"
```

Or use the `@` modifier on them so they are treated verbatim, [see this question for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c):

```
@"T:\his\is\my\source"
```

---

Side note: It is probably better to either pass your paths in as command line arguments, or use a config file, rather than hardcoding them into your code. For example (untested code):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Two arguments must be supplied!");
    }

    //Add error checking as appropriate
    //You could also format the arguments like -s:... and -d:...
    //Then the order of the arguments will not matter

    string sourcePath = args[0];
    string destinationPath = args[1];
}
```

Comment: I've added the ellipses only to show that there are other fields. I don't have them in my actual code. The problem was the variable declaration which Dmitry already mentioned.

Comment: @diiN__________ Note my opening comment "Assuming you have copied the code directly" and there are 3 main mistakes with the code you posted whereas Dmitry only showed one. Next time post an [MCVE] otherwise you'll get extra info on what is wrong with your code like I posted