# C# run PStool from FORM

Tags: c#, cmd

i want to run pstool from windows form.
i tried the code:

```
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\\PSTools\\PsExec.exe \\\\" + dnsName+" CMD";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
```

but it open the command lint and not running the command:"C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe \\" + dnsName+" CMD"

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you're tell it to run `cmd.exe`, and trying to get cmd to execute a command. Try executing just the program you want, or changing the cmd arguments to include `/k`.

Comment: the command to run the pstool is:"c:\pstool.exe \\ip cmd"
how to write it on the argument?

Comment: ok it's working.  i add /k to argument.

startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\\PSTools\\PsExec.exe \\\\" + dnsName+" CMD";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly executed PsExec by setting it's exe into FileName. The arguments that are accepted by PsExec can go in the Arguments property, like so:

```
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\PSTools\PsExec.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"\\{0} CMD", dnsName);
```

Keep in mind that once you indicated with @ that you're after a [verbatim string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c) you no longer need to escape your back-slashes.