# How to import an external image file using Unity FileInfo?

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

I'm going to make a card-matching game.

Images do not exist in Assets,

Be on the external path.
(for example >> C:// ..)

I want to use FileInfo of System.IO rather than Unity's www function.

How do I work?

Comment: DirectoryInfo and FileInfo are not working in standalone build (e.g. Android or iOS)

Comment: I'm currently developing games for Unity. not iOS, and Android

Comment: are you kidding me? How can you develop a game for Unity? Unity is not a deployable device/platform.

Comment: When you build the app, you have to specify the target platform, Unity is definitely not!

Comment: Oh, Sorry.. I misunderstood. I just don't build with Android, Since the test will be conducted only on the PC. @David

Comment: Because this is my personal project! @David

Comment: @최성원 I can't join chat at this time. If you have problem with the dup you can let me know here

Comment: @Programmer I have one question. What does " @ " mean in a @ filepath?

Comment: You need to escape "\" in the path name. @ is used to make it auto escape so that you don't need to escape all the "\". See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c) for more info.

Comment: @Programmer 
It really helps a lot. I want to adopt your answer.

Comment: Then go ahead. Happy coding

Comment: Thank's a lot... very thank you :D

Comment: @Programmer Are you here?