# Replacing \r in String C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am having a heck of a time replacing a newline character in a string inside on Azure Function. This code runs fine as console app

```
string str = "24\n";
str = str.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty)
```

But inside of Azure Function the \n does not go away. Are there alternative methods to replacing a newline other than System.Environment.NewLine?

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c

Comment: You need to assign it to `str`... `str = str.Replace....`

Comment: How do you see it doesn't work in Azure Function?

Comment: When you have replaced \r and \n, you don't need to replace the combination (Environment.Newline) also

Comment: @GiladGreen the reassignment is there in code, just forgot to put in sample.

Comment: @Mikhail not working means if I run the function locally the string is unchanged after above code sample

Comment: @HansKesting I now that, but I was hoping that would handle all situations

Comment: Is the current edit closer to the real code? You do *not* want that `@` in front of the "\n". You *do* want to interpret that as newline, instead of backslash+n

Comment: @HansKesting it is exact now

Comment: No repro. The code removes the newline. There's nothing wrong with replace. .NET does recognize `\r` and `\n`. Throwing replacements "hoping it would handle all situations" when there's no problem to begin will only lead to trouble. What are you trying to do? What is the actual string that you want to replace and how do you know that the replacement failed? Are you sure there *is* a newline in there?

Comment: A lot of times people confuse the debuger's display for the actual string and think their string contains a backslash when it's only an escaped character like .. a newline. Perhaps the *opposite* happened here? The string *does* contain a backslash and n when it should contain a newline?

Comment: When running on Azure Functions, is this the EXACT code you have? Or are  you taking the string input from a binding or some other input? How are you debugging this and observing the behavior?

Comment: The last replace feels kind of redundant. What other common newline characters are there?