# Find replace text with '(' and ')' characters in svg file using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, file, svg

I would like to replace certain text throughout an SVG file using regex.

For example, I might have many attributes like the following in the file:

```
<g clip-path="url(#clipId0)" fill="none" stroke="rgb(150,150,150)" stroke-opacity="0.14902" stroke-width="0.425" >
<polyline points="17001.1,7859.91 17018.7,7859.91 17018.7,7901.08 17001.1,7901.08 17001.1,7859.91 " />
<polyline points="17018.7,7880.5 17001.1,7880.5 " />
<polyline points="17018.7,7883.44 17001.1,7883.44 " />
</g>
```

and I would like to replace

```
stroke="rgb(150,150,150)"
```

to be

```
stroke="rgb(100,100,100)"
```

Note that the original numerical values will likely be different at each instance, but I want to change them all to (100,100,100)

I tried the following:

```
        //Make SVG monochrome
        string svgText = File.ReadAllText(svgPath);
        Regex.Replace(svgText, "stroke=\"rgb(.*,.*,.*)\"", "stroke=\"rgb(100,100,100)\"");
        File.WriteAllText(svgPath, svgText);
```

But of course, it did not work, because of the parenthesis.  When I use an escape before the parens '\(' and '\)', I get the red squiggle error indicating an unrecognized escape character, but for regular expressions, I should escape parenthesis characters so that they are taken literally since they are special characters for regex.  Correct?

How should I use regular expressions in this string to achieve what I want?

Comment: Why would you do that instead of using an XML parser that already exists?

Comment: As great and powerful as regexes are, a built in parser will fix it all up for you :)

Comment: Actually, I haven't tried parsing svg attributes with an XML parser.  The attributes are more complex than I'm used to.  Any examples.  I actually looked and didn't find one.

Comment: Look in the System.Xml namespace.  I usually use the XmlDocument class.  You can query nodes with XPath.

Comment: You'll need to escape the backslashes to stop them from being interpreted as the start of an escape sequence. eg. `"stroke=\"rgb\\(.*,.*,.*\\)\""`. Alternately, you should be able to use a verbatim string literal, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c

Comment: Can I manipulate the stroke with the XML parser easily without worrying about the entity type?  Stroke can be part of a variety of entity types from what understand circles, blocks, lines, polylines?  If not, that's why I was looking at doing a simple find replace.

Comment: You are looking for something like `svgText = Regex.Replace(svgText, @"stroke=""rgb\(\d{1,3},\d{1,3},\d{1,3}\)""", "stroke=\"rgb(100,100,100)\"");`, but really - use xml parser instead.

Comment: Evik--just an FYI, the number could be one or two characters. 0 or 50 or 255 for example.

Comment: @EdwardBagby that's what is used in regex above. `\d{1,3}` means "1-3 digits".

Comment: Ah, cheers.  Worked beautifully Evik.  and of couse I made the mistake not to place the modified string back into the variable.  I'll look into using the XML parser.  Just need to get this working asap.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

While not being a C# developer, I would still guess that this works for your regex string:

```
@"stroke=""rgb\(\d+,\d+,\d+\)"""
```

Don't use `.*`, as it will match 0 or more of (almost) any character.

`\d` will match a digit (generally just 0-9, but it can also match various non-Arabic digits in some regex dialects.)

Happy coding!

Comment: Ah ... literals.  Another option.  Thanks!