# Regex Split \r\n

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to split a var on "\r\n"

Here is my code:

```
          var tempRow = row.InnerText.ToString();

                //   "\r\n  08:05 PM\r\n  963\r\n  Chicago Cubs K. Hendricks -R\r\n  \r\n  \r\n  \r\n   \r\n  -1&frac12;\r\n  +130\r\n  \t\r\n......"

                string[] tempItem = Regex.Split(tempRow.ToString(), @"\\r\\n");
```

But my tempItem[]  doesn't split and has 1 element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `@` ([Verbatim string literal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)) before the string, you do not need to escape backslashes:

```
string[] tempItem = Regex.Split(tempRow.ToString(), @"\r\n");
```

For more information on Verbatim Strings, I highly suggest checking out this link: [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c)