# RichTextBox text causing error in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make my program display text into a text box but when I paste the text it causes errors

```
richTextBox1.Text = "/give @p sign 1 0 {    BlockEntityTag: {        Text1: "{\"text\":\"BUY FOR\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/playsound ui.button.click master @a ~ ~ ~ 10 2\"}}",        Text3: "{\"text\":\"2           LVL\",\"color\":\"white\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/scoreboard players tag @p add SHOP2\"}}"    },    display: { Name: "XP SIGN"    }}";
```

> Error CS1002  ; expected  MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1056  Unexpected character '\'    MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1002  ; expected  MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1513  } expected  MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1002  ; expected  MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1513  } expected  MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1002  ; expected  MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1010  Newline in constant MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1519  Invalid token '";' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs
>
> Error CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   MSC C:\Users\Aprute\Desktop\Minecraft Shop Creator\MSC\MSC\Form1.cs

Comment: You have several unescaped double quotes in the literal. Just escape them.

Comment: Thanks could you tell me or show me how?

Comment: Prepend a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your text as such:

```
richTextBox1.Text = @"/give @p sign 1 0 {    BlockEntityTag: {        Text1: ""{\""text\"":\""BUY FOR\"",\""bold\"":true,\""clickEvent\"":{\""action\"":\""run_command\"",\""value\"":\""/playsound ui.button.click master @a ~ ~ ~ 10 2\""}}"",        Text3: ""{\""text\"":\""2           LVL\"",\""color\"":\""white\"",\""bold\"":true,\""clickEvent\"":{\""action\"":\""run_command\"",\""value\"":\""/scoreboard players tag @p add SHOP2\""}}""    },    display: { Name: ""XP SIGN""    }}"
```

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you changed for it to work.

Comment: The usage of the verbatim string literal and escaping " (using "" instead) did the trick.
Here's more info and a link to Jon Skeet's explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/556142/10713658

Comment: @Aprute Sorry for the late reply. There are two characters that you need to escape in your original text, `\` and `"`, which should be escaped `\\` and `\"`. However, I used a verbatim string( notice the `@`) which only requires you to escape the `"` to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

As sticky _bit* has pointed out, you need to escape any quotes within your string.

i.e.

```
richTextBox1.Text =  "/give @p sign 1 0 {    BlockEntityTag: {        Text1: \"{\"text\":\"BUY FOR\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/playsound ui.button.click master @a ~ ~ ~ 10 2\"}}\",        Text3: \"{\"text\":\"2           LVL\",\"color\":\"white\",\"bold\":true,\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/scoreboard players tag @p add SHOP2\"}}\"    },    display: { Name: \"XP SIGN\"    }}";
```