# Why I got different result from the same hard-coded string value compare to string from db?

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
string regex = Convert.ToString(itemDtlValid.Value); 
string input = itemLst.Value;  
string strRegex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\r\\t\\n ./?;:\"'`!@#$%^&*()\\[\\]{}_+=|\\\\\\-~,]*$";             
Regex re = new Regex(regex);
int comparer1 = regex.CompareTo(strRegex);
int comparer2 = String.CompareOrdinal(regex, strRegex);
```

data in the right column is the value that i have in db for itemDtlValid.Value:

[image]

itemDtlValid.Value i got from db which have same value as strRegex.

But then when i compare those two strings, comparer1 and comparer2 don't return 0.

Does anyone know why this happen? How to get comparer1 and comparer2 to return 0?

Comment: Maybe it's about escaping and unescaping.

Comment: Can you please share the value of `regex - (itemDtlValid.Value)`

Comment: this is the data i have in db for itemDtlValid.Value                                                      
^[a-zA-Z0-9\\r\\t\\n ./?;:\"'`!@#$%^&*()\\[\\]{}_+=|\\\\\\-~,]*$

Comment: @TrầnHoàn, when I quickwatch itemDtlValid.Value it has same exact value as strRegex

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c

Comment: I've found the problem, it's true that it's about escaping and unescaping. Thanks all for the response