# RegEx to match string with digits and characters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a `regex` to match one or two `digit`s, followed by the `character` "M", followed by two `digits`, and then matching anything else, but it doesn't quite work:

I have this `regex` pattern:

```
string astring = "3M90-75";
string sPattern = "^\\d{1}M\\d{2}}$";
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(astring, sPattern))
{
     //It's a match.
}
```

Comment: What you posted *isn't* a match. `\\d{2}}$` means two digits to the end of the input

Comment: Try the following: `\dM\d{2}.*` or `^\dM\d{2}.*`

Comment: To avoid escaping backslashes in a regex, you can precede the string with an `@`: [What's the @ in front of a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556142/1115360).

Answer (score 0):

Use `^\d{1,2}M\d{2}.*`:

- `\d{1,2}M` One or two digit before M
- `\d{2}` Two digit after M
- `.*` To include the rest of string